# SSH into MacBook Pro through router

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, ssh

I have two MacBook Pros on my home network. I have followed the advice in the below question to be able to SSH into them:

> [How do you run a SSH server on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/104929/how-do-you-run-a-ssh-server-on-mac-os-x)

However, how would I issue the command to SSH into them from:

1. Within my home wireless network?
2. From a work computer outside of my home network?

My home network is using a Linksys WRT54G router and both computers are connected wirelessly.

Comment: just a shot in the dark but check out http://www.chaoticsoftware.com/ProductPages/NetworkBeacon.html

Answer (score 4):

For computers on your local network you use the private IP address e.g.

`$ ssh 192.168.0.1`

To connect from outside your network then you need the IP address of your router and you need to make sure that you have port 22 routed to the appropriate machine on your local network, and then you can just do:

`$ ssh ww.xx.yy.zz`

where ww.xx.yy.zz is your external (public) IP address.

Comment: http://whatismyip.com/ will show you your external IP

Comment: So from outside, I wont be able to choose which machine I ssh into?

Comment: You will need to specify in your router settings which local IP address receives incoming connections on port 22. This is because you only have one external IP address. If you need to access more than one machine you'll have to use port mapping e.g. port 22 -> 192.168.0.1:22, port 10022 -> 192.168.0.2:22, port 10122 -> 192.168.0.3:22, etc.

Comment: On your LAN, you can also use Bonjour names, like $ ssh user@MyMacBook.local  
If you want to get classy, look into DynDNS.com to assign a domain name to your router (it's free) and check out Tomato Router Firmware (google that) to have your router automatically update your dns server if your dynamic IP ever changes. With that firmware, you can also designate certain ethernet hardware addresses to be assigned static IPs (through DHCP) on your network, so you don't have to reforward when the LAN IP would otherwise change.